# tkinter python icons won't show up in window

Tags: python, tkinter, icons, .ico

I am trying to add an icon to my windows in python, I have got a .ico file, 16x16 in size, but when I run this script, the windows icon just looks like this: [link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=opera&hs=d2P&biw=1366&bih=631&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=3KxYW6KWMoK5gQa0xryQBw&q=windows%20sheet%20of%20blank%20paper%20icon&oq=windows%20sheet%20of%20blank%20paper%20icon&gs_l=img.3...32499.33078.0.33227.6.6.0.0.0.0.141.577.4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.img..1.0.0....0.wqyERSQyg3Q#imgrc=JVJ0Bj2fJUZIjM:), it doesn't show my custom icon. The .ico file is in the same location as the python file.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk
c = 650
window = tk.Tk()
back = tk.Frame(width=700, height=c)
back.pack()
window.title("Notifications")
window.iconbitmap("image.ico")
window.mainloop()
```

How do I get my icon to show up properly on the window?

Comment: Your code looks fine, I'd guess your .ico file is broken.

Comment: @Novel To make the .ico file I got a png, cropped and resized it and then changed the file extension to .ico, as described on this guide: http://usingpython.com/using-tkinter/

Comment: Ah no, that won't work. You need to use an image program that can convert the file, you can't just rename it. Try your favorite image editor to convert the file to a .ico file. I use the free program GIMP, and there are some free conversion websites too.

Comment: @Novel I will try that, thanks. What is the standard size for an icon, as I used 16 by 16 but I don't know if it can be bigger.

Comment: Go big. The computer will resize it to fit where it needs to go, and a big image scaled down looks a lot better than a small image scaled up. I usually use 128x128 so that the file is still a reasonable size for embedding, but if you don't care about file size go with 512. Also, it does not have to be square, and it can use the alpha channel if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use an image converter. You shouldn't rename the extension of the file to `.ico`.
You can use an online converter too, there are many.